# How to extract pattern using sed and awk command?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a text message in a bash script which I am trying to extract a part of it within a pattern. For example my text string looks like:

```
(cert_a='aaa',cert_b='-----START\nabcdEFGHij\nKLMN\nO/PqR\n-----END\n')This is a sample text..
```

This is part of a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

test="(cert_a='aaa',cert_b='-----START\nabcdEFGHij\nKLMN\nO/PqR\n-----END\n')This is a sample text.."

sample_text=$test

echo $sample_text | busybox sed 's/cert_b='/cert_b='\\n/g' | awk "/-----START/,/-----END/"
```

This script will be executed by non-root user. It is working fine for root user.

Now I want to remove all `\n`ewline characters and extract only the string inside `-----START,-----END`. Hence my output should be:

```
-----START
abcdEFGHij
KLMN
O/PqR
-----END
```

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to cause the literal `\n` character sequence to be converted into a newline? You can use `echo -e {your_string_with\nin_it}` or with `printf`

Comment: @dawg, I have updated my OP. The issue is I am trying to do this as a non-root user.

Comment: Your script ouputs what you expect, it matches with what you define after "Hence my output should by:". Do you get wrong output? Please post the wrong output.

Comment: `test="-----START\n` You input contains `n` not `\n` in your bash script. It's not the same as the input presented. It is uncertain to me if your input contains newline characters o contains ```\``` `n` two characters.

Comment: @Preeti: `echo` and `printf` are not governed by user privilege *usually* and if they are restricted then `awk` and `sed` are likely restricted as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first replace two characters `\` `n` by a newline character.

```
text=$(cat <<EOF
-----START\nabcdEFGHij\nKLMN\nO/PqR\n-----END\n'This is a sample text..
EOF
)
echo "$text" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' | awk "/-----START/,/-----END/"
```

Note: in your script, `"\n"` is just `n`. If you want to preserve `\` , you have to write `"\\n"` or `'\n'` or use a here document as above.

Comment: Hello @KamilCuk, thank you for the update. Your solution works fine on Ubuntu. But i am trying this on a Raspberry Pi and there it is not working. I get the same text as input. On Pi, the script is executred by non-root user. Is this the issue?

Comment: Work fine on my "raspberry pi". The hardware is very not important. `the script is executred by non-root user. Is this the issue?` No.

Comment: Strange. I don't understand why it's not working for me.

Comment: Please post the output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` `awk --version` or `awk -W version` and `sed --version`. Please post them _from the same environment_ you are executing - be it interactive terminal or from _inside_ the script you are executing.

Comment: No resilut for `echo $BASH_VERSION`. For `awk --version` `BusyBox v1.35.0`, for `sed --version` `This is not GNU sed version 4.0`. Linux is a custom Buildroot based

Comment: I think `busybox sed` has different functionality or syntax..

Comment: `echo "$text" | busybox sed 's/\\n/\n/g' | busybox awk "/-----START/,/-----END/"` works fine for me. `BusyBox v1.30.1 (Raspbian 1:1.30.1-6) multi-call binary.` If I would were to pick up my magic ball and guess, I would guess you are not testing the exact code as presented. Otherwise, I guess your environment might be broken. Do you have python or perl? Write it in them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. By mistake I was using `"s/\\n/\n/g"`, changing it to single quotes worked..

Comment: Hello @KamilCuk, sorry for bringing this up again. I have a slightly different input than OP and your solution didn't work for this. The input is `(cert_a='aaa',cert_b='-----START\nabcdEFGHij\nKLMN\nO/PqR\n-----END\n')This is a sample text..` And I am trying with `busybox sed 's/cert_b='/cert_b='\\n/g'`. Can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` solution. We could use `match` function of `awk` and could deal with all requirements within single `awk` itself.

```
-----START\nabcdEFGHij\nKLMN\nO/PqR\n-----END\n'This is a sample text..
EOF
)

echo "$text" | 
awk '
match($0,/-----START\\n.*----END/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/\\n/,ORS,val)
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo $test  awk | \
            sed -n '/-----START/,/-----END/{//!p}' | \
            tr -d '\n' | sed s/$/'\n'/
```

gives `abcdEFGHijKLMNO/PqR` as output.

- The first awk command I guess is needed to actually create a multiline text?
- Second line extracts the lines *between* the two tags `-----START` and `-----END`.
- Last line removes all `\n` but adds a final one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -n '/^-*START$/,/^-*END$/p' <(sed 's/\\n/\n/g' <<<"$sample_text")
-----START
abcdEFGHij
KLMN
O/PqR
-----END

$ awk '/^-*START$/,/^-*END/$' <(awk 'gsub(/\\n/,"\n")' <<<"$sample_text")
-----START
abcdEFGHij
KLMN
O/PqR
-----END

$ awk -F'\\\\n' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i}' <<<"$sample_text"
-----START
abcdEFGHij
KLMN
O/PqR
-----END
```